# Priority of SonarQube Cobol Plugin Copy Directories

Tags: sonarqube, cobol

I have a question related to the SonarQube COBOL plugin.

There is a parameter which allows the user to specify multiple paths of copybook directories: sonar.cobol.copy.directories

Due to a configuration management issue beyond my control, our implementation may contain two copybooks of the same name with different contents. Under this situation we may have the most current copybook in directory A and the less current copybook in directory B.

My question is this. If I set sonar.cobol.copy.directories to c:\directory_a, c:\directory b, and each directory contains a copybook with the same name, which one will SonarQube associate with the COBOL source code?

Comment: Questions about SonarSource commercial products should be asked to SonarSource commercial support.

Comment: couldn't you make a single copybook with a redefines at the end? Then you would have essentially both copybooks depending on which reference you use? as @Pierre-Yves states, you will need to get in touch with the vendor.

Comment: In addition, isn't just doing it, and the age-old-envrionment-idenpendent technique of looking at the output going to tell you your answer, rather than hoping that someone has an identical set-up to you, and is also happy to do the looking for you?